# How to prove that every cut edge of a graph is at the matching M, if M is perfect and G is odd

Tags: graph-theory

I'm having some trouble with playing with matchings. How can I proceed with the following proof?

Suppose G has a perfect matching M and all vertices of G are odd. Prove that every cut edge of G is in M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the handshaking lemma (every graph has an even number of odd-degree vertices).
Suppose $G$ is such a graph and let $e$ be a cut edge. Consider the graph $G-e$. It has two components, each of which has all odd vertices except one. So each component has an odd number of vertices, and therefore can't contain a perfect matching. So every perfect matching in $G$ has to use the cut edge.

Comment: So simple! Thanks a lot!